# not insert due to error in the insert trigger

Tags: sql-server

How can I get All the records that did not insert due to error in the insert trigger?

there was a problem in  DB and there was a trigger in my tables to send the data to another Instance,
all the insert action to the main table was terminated, how can I retrieve these record back

Comment: Add TRAY, CATCH block to identify the problem.

Comment: the problem there was no insert occurred due to this error and many records were not inserted, I added try-catch but the user thinks he added all these records already, how can I get these records back so I can reinsert them.

Comment: is there a log command that shows me all these records that were not inserted due to this error.

Comment: I am not sure you can get those records, but by adding try catch block you can at least identify and fix the problem.

Comment: Is it possible you can provide the sample data and code, so that someone can help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I already have try catch block, but the data was not inserted, this is my problem now, I need a way to retrieve the lost records.

Comment: Without context, the short answer is: you can't. This is one reason why trigger-based replication is a problem that requires careful consideration during design and coding. The process that inserts (or otherwise modifies the contents of your table) must employ some sort of logging / retry mechanism to avoid loss of data.